# How to find the number of solutions of modular equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the number of solutions of  `= x (mod m)`

Comment: The title states m is prime, but the question states m is the product of 2 primes. As long a x, p and q are co-prime it may not matter.

Comment: It looks like this is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: x**2 = x^2 = x*x right? x^2 is always bigger than x mod m unless x = 0 and m = whatever or x = 1 and m > 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a a problem in number theory (modulus algebra), not a programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `p` and `q` be the primes.

You can break a modular equation into separate equations if the factors are coprime.

This means that `**2 = x (mod m)` is equivalent to `**2 = x (mod p)` and `**2 = x (mod q)`.

Each of these can be factorized as `x(x-1)=0 => x=0 or x=1`.

So you know that x is 0 or 1 modulo p, and x is 0 or 1 modulo q.  Each choice has 1 solution modulo m by the chinese remainder theorem so there will be 4 solutions.

2 are easy (x=0 and x=1).  The other two can be found with the extended Euclidean algorithm as follows:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    x,y = 0,1
    lx,ly = 1,0
    while b != 0:
        q = a/b
        (a, b) = (b, a%b)
        (lx, x) = (x, lx-q*x)
        (ly, y) = (y, ly-q*y)        
    return (lx, ly)

p=7
q=11
m=p*q
(lx, ly) = egcd(p,q)
print lx*p%m,ly*q%m
```